# Force use of RSS 0.92 feed

Tags: rss

Just wondering if there was an elegant way to force WordPress to use the RSS 0.92 feed at all?

The reason I ask is that we have added some custom XML tags to a site's feed so that an accompanying iOS app can pull certain data from the feed - WordPress has recently deprecated RSS 0.92 in favour of RSS 2.0 and this is breaking the app, so reverting to RSS 0.92 as a short term fix would be ideal.

I will very much look forward to any thoughts you might have!

Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean RDF/RSS 1.0 feed?

It is not deprecated and should be available just fine at `/feed/rdf`

To force RSS 2.0 links to use RSS 0.92 template try this:

```
remove_action( 'do_feed_rss2', 'do_feed_rss2' );
add_action( 'do_feed_rss2', 'do_feed_rss' );
```

Comment: Hi Rarst, Thanks for taking the time to reply to my question - I was actually thinking of /feed/rss which now seems to be displayed in RSS 2.0 format - any ideas how I could I could push it back to 1.0?

Comment: @Alex could you possibly mean RSS 0.92 one? Because 1.0 is RDF as above.

Comment: Sorry - that's the one I should be talking about! It looks like a redirect of some kind is forcing the display of the RSS 2.0 version. Again, any ideas on how to make sure the 0.92 is used?

Comment: Hi Rarst, Thank you so much! The filter worked perfectly :) Let's consider this one answered!